# NavigationBar change color itself

Tags: ios, swift, colors, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have 2 VCs.
In both i written the code to NavigationController appearance but when I return from second VC to first, I've got everything black...

First VC:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.init(red:47/255.0, green:158/255.0, blue:249/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Second VC:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

So why it doesn't load colours from viewDidLoad when i back to first VC?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because your first ViewController is already loaded, put your navigation bar setup in `viewWillAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super. viewWillAppear()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.init(red:47/255.0, green:158/255.0, blue:249/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```